# Terraform provider restapi: How do I ignore reading response

Tags: terraform

I am doing a PUT/POST on an api which does not return anything in response body. In that case terraform always throw the following error since the response body is empty.

I am using **terraform-provider-restapi** to place a PUT/POST call to **slack**. Here is my provider config.

```
provider "restapi" {
  update_method = "PUT"
  id_attribute = "username"
  write_returns_object = false
  uri = "https://hooks.slack.com/services"
  headers = {
    "Accept" = "text/plain"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
  }
}
```

Since slack rest call **doesn't** return anything, and **terraform-provider-restapi** is trying to read the response, which ends up throwing the following error.

```
unexpected end of JSON input
```

I want to ignore reading the response by **terraform-provider-restapi**. Is there any option available?

Comment: Are you writing a custom Terraform provider/resource? Or is this using an existing one? It would be helpful if you could provide an [mcve] here or at least as much as possible.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my question. Hope it makes some sense now.